# Adobe Illustrator 24 : how use the magic wand on an empty area between to layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

On Photoshop I can easly do that but on Illustrator I can't and I don't understand why

I have two stars :

[image]

The content of theses stars is empty. There are only theirs black borders.

I want to select an area between theses stars and color the selected area with a color.

By example I want select this empty area : (the yellow color has been add with window capture tool)

[image]

And fill the selected area with blue color.

With photoshop, I can quicly do that with the magic wand. But on Illustrator, if I select the magic wand tool and click on the area, nothing happen. 
I don't find the solution and I'm very surprised how a simple thing on photoshop doesn't work (or work differently ?)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  The problem you are experiencing is probably because Illustrator is a totally different kind of software compared to Photoshop.  Best to forget about Photoshop's functionality entirely, and find beginner level tutorials for Illustrator. There are lots on youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong tool. Simple/difficult.. it's all relative. Vectors aren't raster.. there's a reason it's different between the apps.

---

Use the **Live Paint Bucket** which is under the Shape Builder tool. Pick a color, then click with the Live Paint Bucket.

The Magic Wand in Illustrator isn't like the Magic Wand in Photoshop. It is used to select *objects* in Illustrator, not regions like in Photoshop. If there's no object then it won't select anything. Without a fill, the Wand sees nothing.

Comment: ok :) I thinked the same (wrong tool utilisation) but I wan't not sure. Initially I had chosen this tools instead photoshop because I wanted create a vector logo for my website